# updating mysql table using where parameter from jtable cell

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable

I have a MySQL Table with Columns (itemCode, itemCount),
and I have a jTable with Columns (itemCode, itemCount, AddItemCount)

I want to update the MySQL table itemCount with the data on the jTable,
but I dont know how to use a where Parameter ( itemCode ) that can change based on the value of itemCode in each jTable row.

in other word, I want to match the databse table itemCode with the jTable itemCode in each Row then updating the itemCount of the matching itemCode.

What I have tried ( which definitely not working at all ) :

```
    int itemCount, addItemCount, totalItemCount; 
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        con.setAutoCommit(false);
        int rows = tabelDetailDO.getRowCount();
        for(int row=0; row<rows; row++) {
            String SQLupdate = "UPDATE tableItem SET ItemCount=? WHERE ItemCode = '"+(String) tabelDetailDO.getValueAt(row, 0)+"' ";
            ps = con.prepareStatement(SQLupdate);
            itemCount = (int) tabelDetailDO.getValueAt(row, 2);
            addItemCount = (int) tabelDetailDO.getValueAt(row, 3);
            totalItemCount = itemCount + addItemCount;
            ps.setInt(1, totalItemCount);
            ps.addBatch();
         }
        ps.executeBatch();
        con.commit();            
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, e);            
    }
```

if I put the SQL Command outside the for loop, it wont get the "row" which is needed as parameter,

while if I put the SQL Command inside the for loop, it will only get the last row updated as the Command will just keep getting repeated in each loop.

it works normally if the where parameter just take one value ( such as from jtextfield ).

Comment: sorry not fluent in proper english and defo not good in explaining thing , what I want to do is

if itemCode on row 0 = "A"
then it will update the A's itemCount 
then it will move on and take the next row
and itemCode now on row 1 should be = "B"

Comment: OK, thanks for the indentation, but that was a minor concern for me. Much greater is question clarity, and again please do consider improving this if possible.

Comment: Sorry, also please [edit] your original question with the clarification. This is too important to be buried in comments.

Comment: Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Some are correct others are not. Follow Java conventions and be consistent. The point of using a PreparedStatment is to write a simple SQL statement where you can replace tokens. Why would you replace the totalItemCount buy not the value from the table? Again be consistent and use the PreparedStatement the way it was designed to be used. You are less likely to make an SQL mistake.

Comment: I tried to edit and clarify my intention, hope it a little bit clearer now

and yes that was a typo, edited it.

Comment: (1-) Cross posted: https://coderanch.com/t/700059/databases/updating-mysql-table-jtable-rows#3284086. It would be nice if you took the time to read the answers given here before wasting the time of other people in another forum as well.

Comment: I registered and posted on coderach because I am frustrated, so I am just trying my luck on other site, this is my fourth time posting a question, and people here always having hard time understanding my intention, as I was stated, I am not fluent in english, and a beginner self-taught java coder, having to understand a piece of code in english making it just worse, so in most of time I need a more complete answer to be able to understand it. I have posted in coderanch too, I apologize again if Iam slow responding, I was sleeping. Thnks

Comment: Pls dont waste time in downvoting, I will gladly delete this post if possible, or close my account here if needed, Thnks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I dont know how to use a where Parameter ( itemCode ) that can change based on the value of itemCode in each jTable row.

I don't understand the confusion. You can specify the parameter the same way you specify the parameter for the "ItemCount":

```
String SQLupdate = "UPDATE tableItem SET ItemCount= ? WHERE ItemCode = ?";
ps = con.prepareStatement(SQLupdate);

for(int row=0; row<rows; row++) 
{
    String itemCode = (String)tabelDetailDO.getValueAt(row, 0);
    itemCount = (int) tabelDetailDO.getValueAt(row, 2);
    addItemCount = (int) tabelDetailDO.getValueAt(row, 3);
    totalItemCount = itemCount + addItemCount;
    ps.setInt(1, totalItemCount);
    ps.setString(2, itemCode);
    ps.addBatch();
}
```

Note, I have never used a batch update so first try getting the logic working without the batch, so you will need to execute the update each time in the loop. Yes I know it is not efficient but you are just testing the SQL.

Then When that works you try using the batch update.

Comment: Thanks, for the helpful answer as always.