# Java Swing: Insert JTable column into mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, swing

I was trying to INSERT data into mysql database from java swing form where I have two textfield value and one table column value. There I am getting problem with my Insertion process. I am trying to Insert the rows of a jtable column into database, but I found there Inserted that value of last row in the database.

**I did the following code.**

```
String customer_name = nametf.getText();
String phone = phonetf.getText();

PreparedStatement ps;
ResultSet rs = null;

String salesQuery = "INSERT INTO `sales`(`Customer_Name`, `Phone`,`Items`) VALUES (?,?,?)";

try {
    ps = my_con.getConnection().prepareStatement(salesQuery);

    ps.setString(1, customer_name);
    ps.setString(2, phone); 

    for(int i=0; i<table1.getRowCount();i++){
        ps.setString(3, table1.getValueAt(i, 0).toString());
    }

    if(ps.executeUpdate() != 0){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"\nSave Succesfully\n\n","Saved",1);
    }
    else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"\nCheck Error\n\n","Error",1);
    }
}
catch (SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(registration.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but I found there Inserted that value of last row in the database.

In your loop you keep setting the 3rd parameter.

You only invoke the `executeUpdate(...)` statement once so only the last row is updated.

You need to execute your SQL statement for every row in the table:

```
for(int i=0; i<table1.getRowCount();i++){
    ps.setString(1, customer_name);
    ps.setString(2, phone); 
    ps.setString(3, table1.getValueAt(i, 0).toString());
    ps.executeUpdate();
}
```

Note you can also do a batch update of the database. Check out: [updating mysql table using where parameter from jtable cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52671116/updating-mysql-table-using-where-parameter-from-jtable-cell/52672310#52672310) for an example of this approach. You will need to combine the code in the question with the code in the answer to see the full batch implementation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But by implementing your code i found the ```for``` loop is continuing to the last row. But the values of two textfield is also Inserting to the database till the row got null value.

Comment: I'm  not sure what you are trying to say. If you have null data in your JTable, then you need to add a check to only update the database if the data is not null. Only you know your exact requirement. I suggested how to fix your SQL problem. The point was if you want to add multiple rows of data to the database then you need to invoke the executeUpdate() method multiple times.